# Alpine image on Docker, apt-get upgrade libpq-dev

Tags: docker-compose, alpine-linux, apt-get

I'm trying to upgrade `libpq`to latest version, because I'm getting this error:

```
SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above
```

In docker compose I tried:

```
docker exec -it vu_app_1 apt-get update
```

Then:

```
docker exec -it vu_app_1 apt-get install libpq-dev
```

But I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libpq-dev is already the newest version (9.6.23-0+deb9u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 59 not upgraded.
```

So how should I upgrade or install to a version above 10 that `libpq`?

Comment: What is your base image? I highly doubt you are on an Alpine distro, as the package manager of Alpine is `apk` and not `apt`.

Comment: This said, if the repository of package your distribution is using do not contain the version you are looking for, you will most likely need to either upgrade your distribution to a later version or add a repository that contains a version of that package that is more up-to-date. But all this is just the theory and having your exact base image would help you get a more accurate answer.